# I want to use inheritance from Main and Second classes in Manager class but I get <<error : ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget>> ...please

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
class Main(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = "main"
        self.cols = 1
        self.Main_firstISS = Button(size_hint = (0.45,0.2) , pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5 , 'y': 0.2})
        self.Main_secISS = Button(size_hint = (0.2,0.1) , pos_hint = {'x':0.8, 'y': 0} , text = "Exit")
        self.Main_thirdISS = Label(text = "Wellcome to Guess Game\n         play and enjoy")

    self.add_widget(self.Main_firstISS)
    self.add_widget(self.Main_secISS)
    self.add_widget(self.Main_thirdISS)
```

---

```
class Second(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = "second"
        self.cols = 1
        self.Second_firstISS = TextInput(hint_text = "What's your guess" , size_hint = (0.2,0.05) , pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5 , 'y': 0.7})
        self.Second_secISS = Button(size_hint = (0.1,0.1) , pos_hint = {'x':0.9 , 'y': 0})
        self.Second_firstISS.bind(on_press=self.callback)

    self.add_widget(self.Second_firstISS)
    self.add_widget(self.Second_secISS)

def callback(self , instance):
    print(f"{self.Second_firstISS.text}")
```

---

```
class Manager(ScreenManager , Main , Second):
    def __init__(self , **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        my_main_page = Main()
        my_second_page = Second()
        my_main_page.__init__()
        my_second_page.__init__()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
class Main(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = "main"
        self.cols = 1
        self.Main_firstISS = Button(size_hint = (0.45,0.2) , pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5 , 'y': 0.2})
        self.Main_secISS = Button(size_hint = (0.2,0.1) , pos_hint = {'x':0.8, 'y': 0} , text = "Exit")
        self.Main_thirdISS = Label(text = "Wellcome to Guess Game\n         play and enjoy")

        self.add_widget(self.Main_firstISS)
        self.add_widget(self.Main_secISS)
        self.add_widget(self.Main_thirdISS)
class Second(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = "second"
        self.cols = 1
        self.Second_firstISS = TextInput(hint_text = "What's your guess" , size_hint = (0.2,0.05) , pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5 , 'y': 0.7})
        self.Second_secISS = Button(size_hint = (0.1,0.1) , pos_hint = {'x':0.9 , 'y': 0})
        self.Second_firstISS.bind(on_press=self.callback)

        self.add_widget(self.Second_firstISS)
        self.add_widget(self.Second_secISS)

    def callback(self , instance):
        print(f"{self.Second_firstISS.text}")

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self , **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        my_main_page = Main()
        my_second_page = Second()
        self.add_widget(my_main_page)
        self.add_widget(my_second_page)
```

Comment: still same eror

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "G:\ON Works\maintest111.py", line 58, in <module>
     Guessgame().run()
   File "C:\Users\naser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "G:\ON Works\maintest111.py", line 54, in build
     return Manager()
   File "G:\ON Works\maintest111.py", line 44, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\naser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 968, in __init__

Comment: super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\naser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 968, in __init__
     super(ScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "G:\ON Works\maintest111.py", line 14, in __init__
     super().__init__(**kwargs)
   File "G:\ON Works\maintest111.py", line 35, in __init__
     self.add_widget(self.Second_firstISS)
   File "C:\Users\naser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 979, in add_widget

Comment: 'ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.')
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.

Comment: There are missing parts of your code. Without them, I can't solve your problem.. You have to post a [mcve]..

Comment: @naserir7 You can try to move all your `add_widget` lines of the `Main` and `Second` classes, by 4 spaces to the right (put them inside the `init` method). See updated answer..

Answer (score 0):

At first all of your init methods are wrong. And there are couple of another mistakes. You can try fix init functions at first, if it won't help you can try to take everything out of init methods like here:

```
class Main(Screen):
    # if you want to redefine init function, you should do it like this
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    # screen is using relative layout, it doesn't have cols and rows!
    # self.cols = 1
    self.Main_firstISS = Button(size_hint = (0.45,0.2) , pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5 , 'y': 0.2})
    self.Main_secISS = Button(size_hint = (0.2,0.1) , pos_hint = {'x':0.8, 'y': 0} , text = "Exit")
    self.Main_thirdISS = Label(text = "Wellcome to Guess Game\n         play and enjoy")
    self.add_widget(self.Main_firstISS)
    self.add_widget(self.Main_secISS)
    self.add_widget(self.Main_thirdISS)

class Second(Screen):
    # same here
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Second, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    self.Second_firstISS = TextInput(hint_text = "What's your guess" , size_hint = (0.2,0.05) , pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5 , 'y': 0.7})
    self.Second_secISS = Button(size_hint = (0.1,0.1) , pos_hint = {'x':0.9 , 'y': 0})
    self.Second_firstISS.bind(on_press=self.callback)
    self.add_widget(self.Second_firstISS)
    self.add_widget(self.Second_secISS)

    # put that function inside the class!
    def callback(self, *args):
        print(f"{self.Second_firstISS.text}")

# you don't need to inherit Main and Second classes
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self , **kwargs):
        # and here
        super(Manager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    my_main_page = Main(name='main')
    my_second_page = Second(name='second')
    self.add_widget(my_main_page)
    self.add_widget(my_second_page)
```